# ¿Será posible pasar variables desde ASP.NET VB a JavaScript? ¿Cuál es la forma?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, sweetalert

Tengo una gran duda: necesito pasar unos datos desde asp.net para mostrarlos en un sweetalert2. Quería saber si hay alguna manera. Estuve buscando buscando pero no encontré mucho. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: si solo son unas variables usando asp.net establecer los valores en Hidden fields html y javascript lee esos valores

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask], en base a esto modifica tu pregunta agregando lo que intentaste o  investigaste. Te invitamos también a realizar el [tour], para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos!